# Favicon Display Issue in IE

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, favicon

Custom favicon for customer community is correctly displayed using Chrome but not in IE.

In IE, favicon shows on home page but navigating to any other page reverts back to the Salesforce cloud.

On inspecting the element

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://xyz.com/favicon.ico?v=2" />`

is already there.

Comment: are you using bootstrap favicon ?

Comment: Its a simple favicon icon with .ico format. Works fine for other browser like chrome , extra but when tried the same in IE works only on home page and fails for other.  Although ,  done through edit markup only in communitties

Comment: You may need to add manually your favicon

Comment: I have done that also but still it is not visible. Thanks

Comment: Hi All , Its working fine when I click enter or open in a new tab but not when clicked on the same. Thanks